Horror movie about a family ending up in a house in the woods with monsters?
Back when I was in middle school (2009—2012), I watched a scary movie with a bunch of friends and it scared all of us and now I don't know what it's called. My friends don't remember so now this is my only hope of finding it. 
I don't know any actors but I kind of remember what happened. 
A family of, I think, a dad, daughter, and son move into an old house in the woods. Then, these monsters start to attack them. The cops ended up finding a pile of dead bodies in the ground in the family's yard and, toward the end of the movie, a cop is ripped out of his car by one of the monsters. 
I know the dad ends up shooting the monsters with a shotgun and has to go in the ground to get his daughter who got captured by the monsters and I'm pretty sure it ends by the dad shooting a big gas can, blowing up all the monsters.

Welcome to Movies & TV! What country was it set/made in? What language was it in? Can you describe any of the cast, name any of the actors? Please try to provide some more detail, otherwise I'm afraid this question is likely to be put on hold. You might also want to use a more descriptive question title

Sounds like "The New Daughter"

"John James is a writer; his wife has left him. He moves with his middle-school aged daughter and young son to an isolated house off a dirt road in South Carolina. The property has an Indian burial mound, which fascinates his daughter, Louisa, who's entering puberty. Strange things: noises on the roof and in the woods, the cat missing, Luisa sleepwalking clutching a straw doll no one's seen before. She visits the mound often, staying late, coming home covered with mud. John's younger son, Sam, is frightened. John learns the house has a history and seeks out the previous owner. Louisa's behavior becomes more bizarre. Is there an explanation? An ant farm and a missing babysitter provide clues."

Check out a detailed plot description here.
Preview: 



